# HADOOP HIVE QUERY - SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I write a query in **hive**. it not working
query:

```
hive>> select country ,max(total_count) from (select country, count(airlineid) from airport group by country) t2;
```

it shows expression `group by 'country' is missing`.

Comment: `total_count` is a column? or the result of `count(airlineid)` ?

Comment: You only put group by in sub query but your main query

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems. if you format it you should be able to see it.

```
select
  country, -- you need to add this in group by after t2.
  max(total_count) -- you need to create/alias a column called total_count
from
  (
    select
      country,
      count(airlineid)
    from
      airport
    group by
      country
  ) t2;
```

Fixed SQL -

```
select
  country,  
  max(total_count) max_total_count
from
  (
    select
      country,
      count(airlineid)total_count
    from
      airport
    group by
      country
  ) t2
group by country
;
```